# For with if loop in R, running on the data frame with multiple columns and multiple rows

Tags: r

I have a file with 36 columns, each second column contain gene symbol, each first column contain TPM values for that symbol, this is calculated per transcript, which is located in each third column.

That means that gene symbol in each second column may repeat itself in the next cell and it can happen different number of times for different gene symbols based on the number of transcripts for that gene.
I want to run a for loop in R to sum up all the TPM for the same gene symbol and to move it into the new data frame.

My code is :

```
 for (i in 1:12)
  {
  for (j in 2:length(df$ref_gene_name.i))
    {for (k in 2:length(df$ref_gene_name.i))
    { if (df$ref_gene_name.i[k] == df$ref_gene_name.i[k+1])
        {df1$ref_gene_name.i[j] <- df$ref_gene_name.i[k]}
df1$TPM.i[j] <- df$TPM.i[k] + df$TPM.i[k+1]
      }
    }
  }
```

When I run it I get error message:
Error in if (df$ref_gene_name.i[k] == df$ref_gene_name.i[k + 1]) { : 
  argument is of length zero.
Checking single steps for errors:

```
    k=5
df$ref_gene_name.0[k]
df$ref_gene_name.0[k] == df$ref_gene_name.0[k+2]
```

seems to work and returns a correct values, if it's not the same symbol it is False, if it is the same symbol it is true.

Not sure where is my mistake, appreciate any help.

Data looks like that:

[Data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFqri.jpg)

Comment: My guess would be that the inner loop goes until the length of ref_gene_name.i, so what would ref_gene_name.i[k+1] be?

Comment: You are right, it's NULL, what would be a better solution to that?

Comment: It seems to run on 12 columns once and then stop

Comment: I think the problem are NA values in gene symbol column, if I could remove the whole row that contains NA values in ref_gene_name from the related columns (TPM.1, ref_gene_name.1) it may work.

Comment: Could you post a sample of your data?

Comment: I've attached it as an image link above, I think it's better visually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a data structure as the below randomized data (seeded for reproducibility), consider the following where you sum **within** columns and then **across** columns:

1. First, build a list of dataframes that subset original dataframe for every 3 columns.
2. Then, run an aggregation within each dataframe to sum *TPM* grouped by *ref_gene_name*.
3. Lastly, run a chain merge across all dataframes to include all *TPM* columns and *ref_gene_name* and include a sum across all *TPM* columns

**Data** *(where gene names is statistical/numeric, closed/open sourced, programs/languages)*

```
gene_name <- c("SAS", "Stata", "SPSS", "Julia", "R", "Pandas")

set.seed(41918)

df <- data.frame(
  TPM.0 = abs(rnorm(50))*100,
  transcript_id.0 = replicate(50, paste(replicate(10, sample(LETTERS , 1, replace=TRUE)), collapse="")),
  ref_gene_name.0 = replicate(50, sample(gene_name , 1, replace=TRUE)),
  TPM.1 = abs(rnorm(50))*100,
  transcript_id.1 = replicate(50, paste(replicate(10, sample(LETTERS , 1, replace=TRUE)), collapse="")),
  ref_gene_name.1 = replicate(50, sample(gene_name , 1, replace=TRUE)),
  TPM.2 = abs(rnorm(50))*100,
  transcript_id.2 = replicate(50, paste(replicate(10, sample(LETTERS , 1, replace=TRUE)), collapse="")),
  ref_gene_name.2 = replicate(50, sample(gene_name , 1, replace=TRUE))
)

head(df)
#        TPM.0 transcript_id.0 ref_gene_name.0     TPM.1 transcript_id.1 ref_gene_name.1     TPM.2 transcript_id.2 ref_gene_name.2
# 1  86.142687      YVXKYYGWBA           Stata 139.16500      IYIJLZITLR            SPSS  42.39001      LFCAKYBJKI            SPSS
# 2 133.150120      YZGWGGFKXG            SPSS  19.46897      TULSBXMZPE             SAS  88.39766      AUSWZRNRNZ           Stata
# 3 139.804035      ZHPLNRNYWN          Pandas 166.69469      WLUNYEPGAQ               R 103.52094      CRERVAUSDU            SPSS
# 4 146.847943      OTKELYDWDC            SPSS  66.93809      LLOCPRBUZS               R  62.43820      QZYZINREYO             SAS
# 5  89.437472      NMAHZLRXJX            SPSS  49.17413      VCEDDIBJHA           Julia 148.03048      LTHJEDOPDB           Julia
# 6   5.584601      WJLKHEBYYB           Stata  88.22947      RERMEUCXGL            SPSS  61.42689      HHGRPSVALV             SAS
```

**Processing**

```
df$X <- NULL              # BE SURE TO REMOVE ANYTHING BEFORE FIRST TPM

# LIST OF DATAFRAMES (EVERY 3 COLUMNS)
df_list <- lapply(seq(1, ncol(df), 3), function(i) {
  tmp <- df[, c(i,(i+2))]
  # NORMALIZE GENE INDICATOR COLUMN NAME
  colnames(tmp)[2] <- "ref_gene_name"

  # WITHIN SUM
  aggregate(.~ref_gene_name, tmp, FUN=sum)
})

# CHAIN MERGE ACROSS ALL DATAFRAMES
wide_df <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="ref_gene_name", all.x=TRUE), df_list)

# ACROSS SUM: ALL TPM COLUMNS
wide_df$TPM_All <- Reduce(`+`, wide_df[grep("TPM", names(wide_df))])

wide_df
#   ref_gene_name     TPM.0     TPM.1     TPM.2  TPM_All
# 1         Julia 1284.8478  649.3629 1250.2410 3184.452
# 2        Pandas  530.0559  590.9631  873.6411 1994.660
# 3             R  538.8770  509.3850  254.7034 1302.965
# 4           SAS  287.0210  645.4013  587.1971 1519.619
# 5          SPSS  659.0406 1008.8625  902.4517 2570.355
# 6         Stata 1095.2571  925.9412  781.9734 2803.172
```

Comment: Wow, that worked:). Thanks. The only problem is that now I have one final_df with ref_gene_name and TPM columns, if this is the sum of all TPM from all 12 TPM columns that's not what I need. I need separate 12 TPM columns or 24 columns if the ref_gene_name differs between them in the same order they were before with summed TPM values for each gene in each of 12 TPM columns...

Comment: See update aggregating *within* dataframe subsets and then chain merging all together and summing *across* for *TPM_All* total. Also, each distinct *ref_gene_name* will be given its own row (not additional columns).

Comment: Thanks a lot:). That worked perfect. I wish I could know R at the same level as all of you guys...

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! And we all were beginners once. Keep at it and you'll be on this side -answering SO questions. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
library(dplyr)

# Example Data (NA to simulate a partial line)
df <- data.frame("TPM"=c(0.005,0.0008,0.075),"GeneName"=c("OCT4","TERT","TERT"),"Transcript"=c("a","a","b"),
                 "TPM2"=c(0.005,0.0008,NA),"GeneName2"=c("OCT4","TERT",NA),"Transcript2"=c("a","a",NA))

# New data Frame, 1 column per data type
df2 <- data.frame(colnames(c("TPM","GeneName","Transcript")))
for (i in 1:(ncol(df)/3)){
    e <- i*3
    s <- e-2
    dfn <- df[,s:e]
    colnames(dfn) <- c("TPM","GeneName","Transcript")
    df2 <- rbind(df2,dfn)
}

# group by gene name, sum the TPM values by gene name group and ommit any missing values from incomplete lines.
df2 %>% group_by(GeneName) %>% summarise("sumTPM"=sum(TPM)) %>% na.omit()
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do something, But the result is NA values in the GeneName column, also no similar gene names were combined and remained as multiple copies of the same gene, and no TPM values were summed up for each copy of the gene. The message in response to the last line of the code is :A tibble: 0 x 2
# ... with 2 variables: GeneName <chr>, sumTPM <dbl>

Comment: When I ran your code as is it works fine. But adopting it to mine situation  seems not to work:(...

Answer (score 0):

This might need a bit of adjusting, but something along these lines should work..

```
for (i in 0:11)
{
  for (j in unique(df[,paste0("ref_gene_name.",i)]))
   {

       print(sum(df[df[,paste0("ref_gene_name.",i)]==j, paste0("TPM.",i)], na.rm=T))

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems very easy. However when adopting this code for my data, The df1 remained empty, no error was generated in response to that code.

Comment: You are correct - I modified the code and switched it to a print statement to make it easier for you to customize it for your purposes. Good luck!